# How to interpret tags?

Tags: php, joomla, tags

How can I interpret my own tags in PHP like in joomla?

This is a part of a joomla template file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>">

<head>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<?php JHTML::_('behavior.mootools'); ?>
```

Comment: You type them into your editor. I think what you meant to ask is "How can I *interpret* my own tags in PHP like in joomla?" - please ask the right question.

Answer (score 0):

You should create parser - that parse template with your custom tags - and translate it into proper html -> something like template engine for php (Smarty for example).

Answer (score 0):

If Im understanding you correctly you have a template that you want to use your own tags in.
You can get your template contents with file_get_contents()

```
$content = file_get_contents('path_to_your_template_file');
```

Then you can use preg_replace_callback() to use a regex to match your tags, and a callback function to replace them with whatever you want. The following cod finds this custom tag:

```
$content = preg_replace_callback('/<\$mainNav(.*)\/\$>/',array(get_class($this), 'mainNavCallback'),$content);
```

The function mainNavCallback() receives the contents of the custom tag and can then handle custom attributes,etc.

Hope that helps, your probably going to have to play around with it for a while to find what works for you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to do something like this but wouldn't like to use my tags in strings. For example: `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>">

<head>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<?php //php commands here ?>`

Comment: you may need to create custom tags for all the php in your file so that you can work with the file as a string otherwise how are you going to interpret the tags? Then the file could be just an html file that php iterates through and matches custom tags then your php such as, $this->language; can be handled in callback functions.

Comment: or even maybe some usage of eval() could work for you. Now people are going to comment on how eval is evil. But this may be the non-evil application of the eval tag. But again Im just brainstorming.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried eval(), but it doesn't support <?php ?> tags